# Using STL containers without exception handling, in low memory situation

Tags: c++, stl

I've been trying to deal with low memory situation in my VC++ code.
I've used `std::nothrow` and checking returns value of `new` operator for NULL. Application works fine.

But problem is at very low system memory and it crashes abruptly anywhere especially inside STL containers calls (map, vector, queue etc) and the error is "Exception `bad_alloc`". Obviously these containers cannot allocate required memory so they simply throw `bad_alloc`.

Now since I've used these containers liberally in my code, I just don't want each and every function inside "try...catch" block. It would clutter the code. (And moreover, the code uses *event based* library. So, many of the functions are callbacks. Hence, its not like one or few parent caller function(s) I can put in try/catch block and solve this problem)

Without using try/catch, how can this problem be addressed?

At least can someone please tell which of these containers and methods throw `bad_alloc` (So that I will try putting only that particular code in try/catch block)

Comment: If you have very low memory capacity, you might just not want to use dynamic containers at all, and instead operate on a preallocated, fixed array or something like that.

Comment: Not sure how can I implement that. Last time my code crashed at line similar to this: {std::map<int, std::vector<void*>> MyMap;} And I found its {map} constructor was just trying to allocate default space.

Comment: what do you expect when `std::map` failed to allocate memory? it can't return `null` to you, throw exception is the only way to report error

Comment: When I've worked with embedded systems with very little memory, the use of STL and operator new was banned.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using dynamic_cast or any other features that that it gives you, you can turn off RTTI - that might save you a bit, but probably not enough.

The only other option I can offer is to profile your memory usage, and optimize your code so that you're freeing things you no longer need earlier.

Answer (score -1):

You ask: "how can this problem be addressed?"

Well, what is the problem?

1. "I don't have enough memory to run my program" — procure more
2. "My program uses too much memory" — use less

You can't magically work around it any other way.